# Struts testing JUnit4

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, junit, struts2

A project that Im working on uses Spring and Struts.

Up until now, we we using using Struts 2.1.8.1. All my unit tests extended the [StrutsSpringTestCase](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-junit-plugin/2.2.3/org/apache/struts2/StrutsSpringTestCase.java) which in turn extended the [StrutsTestCase](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-junit-plugin/2.2.3/org/apache/struts2/StrutsTestCase.java#StrutsTestCase). However, this used JUnit 3.8.2 and hence had no annotation support.

For Struts 2.2.3, the dev team [added a Junit4 TestCase](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3403?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs), called [StrutsJUnit4TestCase](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-junit-plugin/2.2.3/org/apache/struts2/StrutsJUnit4TestCase.java?av=f). This test case however, does not the have the supporting functions that [StrutsTestCase](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-junit-plugin/2.2.3/org/apache/struts2/StrutsTestCase.java#StrutsTestCase) did e.g. for issuing struts actions. I tried to find some tutorials using this new test case, but haven't had any luck.

I should mention that I'm trying to use the Rollback annotations, to rollback the automatically rollback database changes that occur during the test.

How exactly am I supposed to use this new [StrutsJunit4TestCase](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-junit-plugin/2.2.3/org/apache/struts2/StrutsJUnit4TestCase.java?av=f)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least the following one works in my computer

```
public class BlaBlaBlaTestCase extends StrutsSpringTestCase {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public String getContextLocations() {
        return "applicationContext_test.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void testWhatever() {
                //...
    }
}
```

the getContextLocations method is important, because this is the method which defines where your applicationContext for testing is.

oh, i'm using junit 4.4

Comment: I wrote a few tests that way. The problem is that I'm trying to write tests which rollback automatically. Rollback annotations were added in Junit4+. I read an article previously that since StrutsTestCase extends XWorkTestCase which extends the junit(3.x) TestCase Base class. Due to this annotations won't work. Hence the StrutsJUnit4TestCase was written.

Comment: oh, i have never used the rollback annotation >.< so well, yes. probably my code wouldn't work if i use rollback annotation T_T

Comment: if you execute this, it still uses Junit 3. Remove the "test" before "testWhatever" and then you'll get the error "no test methods".

Answer (score 4):

Struts2 actions are nothing but simple classes. I suggest you to test them the way you test other classes IMHO.
I've been doing this way for most of my time doing struts2 and barely felt the need to use `StrutsTestCase`. If you design your actions with DI in mind you can inject any dependencies while testing the action.